# How to replace a string with ignoring spaces, carriage return or line breaks in a given text by using C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to replace specific string (this will be different each time so not the given particular example in this question) in a given text but with the following rules: it will ignore space character, carriage return or line breaks

Is this possible?

Take the following HTML document as an example.

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px;">
      <b>
         <a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.monstermmorpg.com\" 
         style=\"color: rgb(6, 69, 173); 
         text-decoration-line: none;    background: none;\" 
         title=\"Calyrex (Pokémon)\"><span style=\"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">&larr;</span></a>
      </b> 
   </td>
</tr>
```

The goal is to replace the following string found within the document above, with something else, let's say `AAA`.

```
<td style="text-align: right;"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://www.monstermmorpg.com" style="color: rgb(6, 69, 173); text-decoration-line: none; background: none;" title="Calyrex (Pokémon)"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">&larr;</span></a></td>
```

The expected result should be

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px;">
      <b>
         AAA
      </b> 
   </td>
</tr>
```

### What I have tried

I have tried using htmlagilitypack, unfortunately is not working in my case because I am not trying to replace single HTML nodes. I need to replace **partial pieces** of the document that may or may not span across several nodes. I have not be able to get htmlagilitypack to do this.

Comment: Why `HtlmAgilityPack` is not working? Share how you tried on that.

Comment: @JamshaidK. because the html is only a fragment not a full page. Believe me I tried every way. I have failed to replace outerhtml of a node or the node itself. Because it throws error at parent node references.

Comment: That is the part where you need to put your logic. If you are not able to systematically track down the desired node you will not be able properly replace that element. It would still be better to attach the HtmlAgilityPack version so people can see what actual problem is in this case.

Comment: @JamshaidK. here example code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yV7VaulP8Ze53BqK_xAsEyWFr3sxG-vh/view?usp=sharing . It can find nodes but there is no way to alter or modify a nodes. I want to modify a nodes which have href in a way I want.

Comment: When you say, it is only a fragment not a full page. Do you mean it won't work because of that? It is not true. It will still load your html into the HtmlDocument. You will have pass the xPath values correctly to filter out your data.

Comment: Why is your text malformed HTML?

Comment: @JamshaidK. it doesnt work you can test. find a node like this and try to modify its outer html       var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

                foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes.ToList())
                {

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - When I take out the `\"` and replace with `"` it works fine.

Comment: @Enigmativity here an example full source code can you test on that with htmlagilitypack? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yV7VaulP8Ze53BqK_xAsEyWFr3sxG-vh/view

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - Please post on something that doesn't require permission to access.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry i just noticed it wasn't properly shared : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yV7VaulP8Ze53BqK_xAsEyWFr3sxG-vh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JamshaidK. sorry i just noticed it wasn't properly shared : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yV7VaulP8Ze53BqK_xAsEyWFr3sxG-vh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - The text in the file you've linked to is different in format fromt he text in the question. You're escaping the double quotes in the question, but not in the text file. Which is meant to be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that traditional html parsing approaches seem to not be working for your use case, have you considered writing a manual parser for this specific use case?

I wrote a short, but working, example of what you may want to consider.

A couple things to keep in mind however, this implementation was written quickly, has no error handling, assumes the target string can fit within memory, and is missing key edge cases. If you wish to consider this solution you should invest in the time to fill the gaps.

This solution simply parses the whole document, ignoring and writing non-target characters and when the target string is identified, writes an alternative string instead.

This may not be the best solution, *I would encourage you to look for off the shelf HTML parsers that provide more functionality.*

```cs
public static void RemoveTargetString(TextReader Reader, TextWriter Writer, string TargetString, char[] CharactersToIgnore, string ReplacementString)
{
    HashSet<char> IgnoreCases = CharactersToIgnore.ToHashSet();

    // our buffer need only be the size of the target string
    char[] buffer = new char[TargetString.Length];

    int currentIndex = 0;

    while (Reader.Peek() > -1)
    {
        // read one character to the end of the buffer marked by index
        if (Reader.Read(buffer, currentIndex, 1) != 0)
        {
            // get the last char in the buffer
            ref char firstChar = ref buffer[currentIndex];

            // if the char is on the ignore list blindly write it and continue
            // dont change index so we overwrite the char in the last spot of the buffer
            if (IgnoreCases.Contains(firstChar))
            {
                // write the char and ignore
                Writer.Write(firstChar);
                continue;
            }

            // check to see if the char is in the right order as the target string
            if (firstChar == TargetString[currentIndex])
            {
                // if it is don't write the buffer, increment index so we keep the char without back tracking
                currentIndex++;

                // if we have found the entire string dump the buffer, write the replacement string
                if (currentIndex == TargetString.Length)
                {
                    // write replacement string instead
                    Writer.Write(ReplacementString);

                    // reset index so we overwrite the buffer
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // check to see if the target string is within something that starts with a partial piece of the target string
                // we should not implicitly assume the character we fail at isn't the start of the target as well
                // if it is we should avoid writing it
                if (firstChar == TargetString[0])
                {
                    Writer.Write(buffer, 0, currentIndex);

                    buffer[0] = buffer[currentIndex];

                    // reset index and start searching for start of target
                    currentIndex = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // since the char at the last position of the buffer wasn't
                    // either the start or within the target string
                    // write the buffer from 0 - last index
                    Writer.Write(buffer, 0, currentIndex + 1);

                    // reset index and start searching for start of target
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    // if for some reason the target string is at the end, but was not complete, we should write the characters in the buffer to the target
    if (currentIndex > 0)
    {
        Writer.Write(buffer, 0, currentIndex);
    }
}

char[] IgnoreCharacters = new char[] { '\n', '\r', ' ' };

string target = "<td style=\"text - align: right; \">\n\r<a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.monstermmorpg.com\"\n\r style=\"color: rgb(6, 69, 173);\n\r text-decoration-line: none;\n\r background: none;\"\n\r title=\"Calyrex (Pokémon)\"><span style=\"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">&larr;</span></a></td>";

StringReader reader = new($"<tr>\n\r<td colspan=\"2\" style=\"background - image: initial; background - position: initial; background - size: initial; background - repeat: initial; background - attachment: initial; background - origin: initial; background - clip: initial; border - top - left - radius: 3px; border - top - right - radius: 3px; \">\n\r<b>{target}</b>\n\r</td>\n\r</tr>");

foreach (char item in IgnoreCharacters)
{
    target = target.Replace(item.ToString(), "");
}

StringWriter writer = new();

RemoveTargetString(reader, writer, target, IgnoreCharacters, "AAA");

Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
```

If you're not familiar with `TextReader` or `TextWriter` these are the base classes for common IO features like `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. You could use this to stream line finding information in files like this:

```cs
char[] IgnoreCharacters = new char[] { '\n', '\r', ' ' };

string target = "Hello World";

string replacement = "Hello Globe";

using StreamReader reader = new("Test.txt");
using StreamWriter writer = new("Output.txt");

RemoveTargetString(reader, writer, target, IgnoreCharacters, replacement);
```

Edit:
Fixed Issue where if the target was in the middle of being identified but failed, a single character was not being written to the output stream causing lossy transcription. Created Test Cases for common edge cases.

For those interested in the performance of this solution it takes ~35 seconds to process a 1,278,518,583 bytes(1.19GB) text file, and uses 9 MB of memory. If additional performance is needed consider replacing `IgnoreCases.Contains(firstChar)` with `Char.IsWhiteSpace(firstChar)` this is ~33% faster.

```cs
static char[] IgnoreCharacters = new char[] { '\n', '\r', ' ', '\t' };

[Theory]
[InlineData("1234", "<div>1234</div>", "<div></div>")]
[InlineData("1234", "<div>1\n\r2\t3\n4\r</div>", "<div>\n\r\t\n\r</div>")]
[InlineData("1234", "\n\r\t1\n\r\t2\r\n\t3\n\t\r4", "\n\r\t\n\r\t\r\n\t\n\t\r")]
[InlineData("1234", "1 2 3 4", "   ")]
[InlineData("1234", " \n\r\t1 \n\r\t2 \n\r\t3 \n\r\t4 \n\r\t", " \n\r\t \n\r\t \n\r\t \n\r\t \n\r\t")]
[InlineData("1234", "123412341234", "")]
[InlineData("1234", "4321", "4321")]
[InlineData("1234", "Hello", "Hello")]
[InlineData("1234", "", "")]
[InlineData("1234", "1/2/3/4", "1/2/3/4")]
[InlineData("1", "1111", "")]
[InlineData("1", "12131415", "2345")]
[InlineData("Abcde", "AbcdAbcde", "Abcd")]
[InlineData("Abcde", "AbcdAbcdeAbcd", "AbcdAbcd")]
[InlineData("12345", "121231234123451234123121", "1212312341234123121")]
public void CommonEdgeCases(string Target, string Input, string Expected)
{
    foreach (char item in IgnoreCharacters)
    {
        Target = Target.Replace(item.ToString(), "");
    }

    StringReader reader = new(Input);

    StringWriter writer = new();

    RemoveTargetString(reader, writer, Target, IgnoreCharacters, string.Empty);

    Assert.Equal(Expected, writer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: A decent solution. So looks like no built-in or 3rd party library for this task?

Comment: No clue unfortunately I specialize in low/high level code library design and optimization, so I'm not up to date on current HTML parsers. Hopefully a more informed person who works with HTML parsing more frequently than I will stop by.

Comment: The problem is that the html piece I have is not a valid full one. It is partial. So that is why htmlagilitypack fails.

Comment: I figured that was the case so I wrote this implementation that avoids making any assumptions about the string it's reading. It doesn't care if it's html or an encrypted char string etc.. =)

Comment: I just had time to test and it is not working unfortunately. Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDvFk0eykCw

Comment: I reviewed the video, I appreciate you taking the time to make it, It allows for far easily trouble shooting. The reason it appears to not work is because the target string was never found. The target string you are looking for does not exist in the document you are searching. It's looking for `"<tdstyle="text-`..  However `test1.txt` does not contain that sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Given the text you posted, this seems to work:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"example.txt");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='mw-jump-link']");
foreach (HtmlNode secondParagraph in nodes.ToList())
{
    var moreNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("AAA");
    var parent = secondParagraph.ParentNode;
    parent.InsertAfter(moreNode, secondParagraph);
    parent.RemoveChild(secondParagraph);
}
doc.Save(@"example2.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are fine with write once read never regular expression :) here is something that might work ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lf0CzZ))

```
var originalData = @"
<tr>
   <td colspan=""2"" style=""background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px;"">
      <b>
         <a rel=\""nofollow\"" target=\""_blank\"" href=\""https://www.monstermmorpg.com\"" 
         style=\""color: rgb(6, 69, 173); 
         text-decoration-line: none;    background: none;\"" 
         title=\""Calyrex (Pokémon)\""><span style=\""color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\"">&larr;</span></a>
      </b> 
   </td>
</tr>
";

var searchString = @"<a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""https://www.monstermmorpg.com"" style=""color: rgb(6, 69, 173); text-decoration-line: none; background: none;"" title=""Calyrex (Pokémon)"">
    <span style=""color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"">&larr;</span>
</a>
";

Console.WriteLine("===== originalData ====");
Console.WriteLine(originalData);
Console.WriteLine("===== originalData ====\n");

Console.WriteLine("===== searchString ====");
Console.WriteLine(searchString);
Console.WriteLine("===== searchString ====\n");

var searchRegexString = searchString.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("\"", "\\\\\"").Replace("(", "\\(").Replace(")", "\\)").Replace(" ", "[ \\n\\r\\t]*");
var searchRegex = new Regex(searchRegexString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var replacedData = searchRegex.Replace(originalData, "***** REPLACED *****");

Console.WriteLine("===== searchRegexString ====");
Console.WriteLine(searchRegexString);
Console.WriteLine("===== searchRegexString ====\n");

Console.WriteLine("===== replacedData ====");
Console.WriteLine(replacedData);
Console.WriteLine("===== replacedData ====\n");
```